# CakePHP controller to save a image as pdf

Tags: php, cakephp, pdf, tcpdf

I have a CakePHP controller that is taking a URL and turning it into a PDF by first turning it into an image. The PDF is being generated properly via TCPDF, but it is only displaying it. How can I save the PDF file on the server instead of just displaying it?

```
<?php
App::import('Vendor', 'TestPdf.tcpdf', array('file'=>'tcpdf'.DS.'tcpdf.php'));

$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetMargins(0, 0, 0);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

foreach($pages as $page)
{
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->setJPEGQuality("100");
    $pdf->Image($page, 0, 0, 210, 0, 'PNG', '', '', false, 300);
}


$pdf->Output('example_001.pdf', 'I');
```

Comment: Do you want to save the PDF file on the server or prompt the user to download and save it?

Comment: George, Save the file on the server. Sorry for the lack of clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a3d6dcb62298ec9d42e9125ee2f5b23a1) the 'I' option tells `TCPDF::Output()` to send the PDF output to the client. To store on the server side, use 'F'.

```
$pdf->Output('example_001.pdf', 'F');
```

Comment: Ok, so I tried this, but it continually errored out until I realized it needed an absolute server path. Thanks for the help, George!

Answer (score 0):

There is a CakePHP plugin that achieves exactly what you want to do and it supports several PDF engines:

- DomPdf
- Mpdf
- Tcpdf
- Wkhtmltopdf (requires additional installation) RECOMMENDED ENGINE

It can also save either to file or stream as a download.

The plugin can be found here:

https://github.com/ceeram/CakePdf

See point 2 under "Usage" for your scenario.